# How to convert back to another timezone in moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have an date that is `2021-07-07 05:00:00` when i saved in db, i saved it in `CET` so saved date time is `2021-07-07 01:00:00` (4 hours behind). So after that i need to show date from db that expected output is  `2021-07-07 05:00:00` but i got different value.

```
moment(obj.from_date).tz('Asia/Dhaka').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss zz');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the momentjs timezone docs @ https://momentjs.com/timezone/ ...
what you need to do is something like:

```
moment.tz(obj.from_date, "CEST").tz('Asia/Dhaka').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss zz');
```

see if that works.